# jquery addclass error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem with jQuery:

```
$('#form-submit').click(function () {

    $('#textarea, #name').removeClass('error-state').addClass('normal-state');

    var myName = $('#name').val();
    var myContent = $('#textarea').val();

    if ( myContent == '' || myName == '')
    {
        $('#textarea, #name').removeClass('normal-state').addClass('error-state');
        return false;
    }

    [more code here]

});
```

This code works good for `#textarea` but doesn't for `#name`, I've check and re-recheck without find the error.

But, if we add:

```
$('#name').val('some value');
```

before `return false;` change the value but the CSS class still the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your code. Consider creating a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Show us some HTML so that we can tell if you have an issue with your selectors.

Comment: can you show us the html for "name"?

Comment: The classes you're adding/removing aren't defined in the stylesheet as specific to some element type(s) are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$('#form-submit').click(function () {

    var arrJEls = $('#textarea, #name');

    arrJEls.each(function(i){
        //See what happens with each element:
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).removeClass('error-state').addClass('normal-state');
    });

    var myName = $('#name').val();
    var myContent = $('#textarea').val();

    if ( myContent == '' || myName == '')
    {
        arrJEls.each(function(i){
            //See what happens with each element:
            console.log($(this));
            $(this).removeClass('normal-state').addClass('error-state');
        });
        return false;
    }

    [more code here]

});
```

Comment: The good thing with jQuery is that you don't have to iterate over each element to apply some function. If the OP's code does not work, this won't either.

Comment: I don't believe that `.each()` function is necessary, if you call `.removeClass(...).addClass(...)` on your `arrJEls` variable it will affect both elements. However it is a good idea to cache the selector(s) in a variable since they can be accessed multiple times.

Comment: I forgot add the console.log() in each element.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/Zpxmr/

And I hope you know that ID's are single use and are only applied to one element

Comment: yes, I've tried with this: console.info( $('#name').hasClass('error-state') ); and i got TRUE at console, but css style still without render. :(

Comment: have you tried changing ID to something else? I suspect that ID named "name" my cause sometimes an issue